# How do I only allow an item to be dropped in a certain place in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

StackOverflow community! For the past few weeks, I have been working on a drag-and-drop for HTML/JavaScript. Basically, I have a circle and two boxes. The circle can be dragged to anywhere on the screen. However, I need it so the circle can only be dropped within one of the two boxes. Despite several days of research, I could not figure out how to do this. Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" 
        content="width=device-width, 
        initial-scale=1.0, 
        user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Drag/Drop/Bounce</title>
  <style>
    #item {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: rgb(245, 230, 99);
      border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
      border-radius: 50%;
      touch-action: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    #box1 {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #box2 {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Drag and Drop</h1>
<div id="box1">
  <div id="item"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="box2"></div>

  <script>
    var dragItem = document.querySelector("#item");
    var container = dragItem;
    
    //Declare Variables
    var active = false;
    var currentX;
    var currentY;
    var initialX;
    var initialY;
    var xOffset = 0;
    var yOffset = 0;
    
    //Add Event Listeners for Touchscreens
    container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);
    
    //Add Event Listeners for Mice
    container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

    function dragStart(e) { //when the drag starts
      if (e.type === "touchstart") { //if its a touchscreen
        initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - xOffset; //set initial x-cordinate to where it was before drag started
        initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - yOffset; //set initial y-cordinate to where it was before drag started
      } else { //if its not a touchscreen (mouse)
        initialX = e.clientX - xOffset; //set initial x-cordinate to where it was before drag started
        initialY = e.clientY - yOffset; //set initial y-cordinate to where it was before drag started
      }

      if (e.target === dragItem) { //if user is dragging circle
        active = true; //the drag is active
      }
    }

    function dragEnd(e) { //when the drag ends
      initialX = currentX; //set the initial x-cordinate to where it is now
      initialY = currentY; //set the initial y-cordinate to where it is now
      
      active = false; //the drag is no longer active
    }

    function drag(e) { //when the circle is being dragged
      if (active) { //if the drag is active
        e.preventDefault(); //the user cant do anything else but drag
      
        if (e.type === "touchmove") { //if its a touchscreen
          currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - initialX; //set current x-cordinate to where it is now
          currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - initialY; //set current y-cordinate to where it is now
        } else { //if its not a touchscreen (mouse)
          currentX = e.clientX - initialX; //set current x-cordinate to where it is now
          currentY = e.clientY - initialY; //set current y-cordinate to where it is now
        }
        
        //Im not sure what this does but it dosnt work without it
        xOffset = currentX;
        yOffset = currentY;
        setTranslate(currentX, currentY, dragItem);
      }
    }

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) { //Im not sure what this does but it dosnt work without it
      el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've also uploaded the code to TryIt for those who prefer: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCF4V2RIT7T4

Comment: Have you read through [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)? It's pretty straight-forward. Seems like you want to read up on the section titled "Define a drop zone". Also, please always post your code right here in your question, rather than at 3rd party locations as those links can die over time, making your question meaningless for those who come across it.

Comment: Also, W3 Schools is well-known to have incomplete, out of date, or just plain incorrect information. Get your information from the source, which is the [Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

Answer (score 1):

In this version you can move the circle only inside the red box. I think you can take that and easily implement the other box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1.0, 
    user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Drag/Drop/Bounce</title>
  <style>
#item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(245, 230, 99);
  border: 10px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, .5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  touch-action: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Drag and Drop</h1>
<div id="item"></div>
<div id="box1">
</div>
<br>
<div id="box2"></div>

  <script>
var dragItem = document.querySelector("#item");
var box1 = document.querySelector("#box1");
var box2 = document.querySelector("#box2");
var container = dragItem;
//Declare Variables
var active = false;
var currentX;
var currentY;
var initialX;
var initialY;
var xOffset = 0;
var yOffset = 0;

//Add Event Listeners for Touchscreens
container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);

//Add Event Listeners for Mice
container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

function dragStart(e) { //when the drag starts
  if (e.type === "touchstart") { //if its a touchscreen
    initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - xOffset; //set initial x-cordinate to where it was before drag started
    initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - yOffset; //set initial y-cordinate to where it was before drag started
  } else { //if its not a touchscreen (mouse)
    initialX = e.clientX - xOffset; //set initial x-cordinate to where it was before drag started
    initialY = e.clientY - yOffset; //set initial y-cordinate to where it was before drag started
  }
  if (e.target === dragItem) { //if user is dragging circle
    active = true; //the drag is active
  }
}

function dragEnd(e) { //when the drag ends
  const box1Size = box1.getBoundingClientRect()
  const elementSize = dragItem.getBoundingClientRect()
  if (elementSize.left >= box1Size.left && elementSize.right <= box1Size.right && elementSize.top >= box1Size.top && elementSize.bottom <= box1Size.bottom) {
    initialX = currentX; //set the initial x-cordinate to where it is now
    initialY = currentY; //set the initial y-cordinate to where it is now
  } else {
    currentX = 0
    currentY = 0
 initialX = 0
    initialY = 0
    xOffset = 0;
    yOffset = 0;
   setTranslate(0, 0, dragItem);
  }
  
  active = false; //the drag is no longer active
}

function drag(e) { //when the circle is being dragged
  if (active) { //if the drag is active
    e.preventDefault(); //the user cant do anything else but drag
  
    if (e.type === "touchmove") { //if its a touchscreen
      currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - initialX; //set current x-cordinate to where it is now
      currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - initialY; //set current y-cordinate to where it is now
    } else { //if its not a touchscreen (mouse)
      currentX = e.clientX - initialX; //set current x-cordinate to where it is now
      currentY = e.clientY - initialY; //set current y-cordinate to where it is now
    }
    
    //Im not sure what this does but it dosnt work without it
    xOffset = currentX;
    yOffset = currentY;
    setTranslate(currentX, currentY, dragItem);
  }
}

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) { //Im not sure what this does but it dosnt work without it
  el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```